# What figure of speech is this statement?

Tags: figures-of-speech

> The cynical indifference of the sea to the merits of human suffering
>   and courage revolted me.

An English professor insisted that the above statement is a metaphor. To me though, it looks like personification since the sea is described as showing indifference towards something. It is clearly being personified.

I would like to know if my view is correct.

Comment: Personification is a type of metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you have provided is best said to employ **personification** or **anthropomorphism**. These two *very* closely related devices attribute human qualities to non-human entities. In your example, we are attributing the human characteristic of cynicism to the sea.

A **metaphor** is a device to compare or equate two things. It is often described as a **simile** without *like* or *as*.

1. He is the black sheep in the family. (metaphor)
2. Her eyes sparkle like the stars. (simile)

Answer (score 1):

In '15, Pope Francis (using a proverb - no man is an island) said: “Dear brothers and sisters, how greatly I desire that all those places where the Church is present, especially our parishes and our communities, may become **islands of mercy in the midst of the sea of indifference!”**  [article](https://www.rappler.com/world/global-affairs/82179-pope-lent-message-globalization-indifference)

[image: POPE]

In your citation

> The cynical indifference of the sea to the merits of human suffering
>   and courage revolted me.

is an attempt to use the proverb and put it into a metaphor. It works ... only if in context the discussion implied that sea = 'the masses of' or 'humanity'.

[image: cartoon]

Answer (score 1):

The literary term is:
pathetic fallacy

> The phrase pathetic fallacy is a literary term for the attributing of
>   human emotion and conduct to all aspects within nature. It is a kind
>   of personification that is found in poetic writing when, for example,
>   clouds seem sullen, when leaves dance, or when rocks seem indifferent.
>   The British cultural critic John Ruskin coined the term in his book,
>   Modern Painters (1843–60).
>   [Pathetic fallacy (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy)
>
> Pathetic fallacy, poetic practice of attributing human emotion or
>   responses to nature, inanimate objects, or animals. The practice is a
>   form of personification that is as old as poetry, in which it has
>   always been common to find smiling or dancing flowers, angry or cruel
>   winds, brooding mountains, moping owls, or happy larks.
>   [Encyclopaedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/pathetic-fallacy)
>
> n. The attribution of human emotions or characteristics to inanimate
>   objects or to nature; for example, angry clouds; a cruel wind.
>   [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pathetic+fallacy)

It's also metaphor and personification, as have been mentioned already.

Comment: To be accurate, a pathetic fallacy refers to attribution of only feelings or emotions to a natural, inanimate, object  - hence the 'pathos'. As described by Ruskin, it also labels an excessive use of this - hence the 'fallacy'. In these ways, it differs from personification which can attribute  any human action to any object. Complaining that your phone has walked away is personification, but not a pathetic fallacy. Whether an indifferent sea is displaying emotion is questionable.